# Sitecore Helix Template(Anders Laub) Azure DevOps Pipeline builds not bringing Views from Feature projects

Tags: pipelines, helix, azure-devops

I have a **Sitecore 9.3** installation on a **VM** and have Visual Studio Code on the host machine. When we build, then code gets pushed from host to VM IIS. This works fine on local to VM.

I have a pipeline that I executes once I push changes to git. When I look at the artifact that gets created, I don't see the views from my **Feature/Foundation** projects in that artifact. It only has the Views from the **Project**. Under the bin I do see the Feature/Foundation dll's. I am using the **SDK Style templates**.

Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I have faced this issue when using SDK project type in SC9.3. We had to include every view file in the SDK csproj file so that HPP pipeline can publish it to the artifacts folder. Normally Helix Project layer will not be using SDK style so it works as usual.

Comment: are you referencing your projects in your HPP project? And how is your pipeline building the solution? Are you just using a std MSBuild to build the HPP project?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by HPP, but I am referencing the projects from Feature and Foundation folder on the Project (Website project. ). Also for Pipeline, I have YAML file that is using VSBuild and copying TDS files.

Comment: Are your view files marked as "Content" ?

Comment: Yes, the files that needs to go are marked as content.